# In a random permutation of the letters of the word MISSISSIPPI, determine the expected number of Is that are followed by an S

Tags: probability

The letters of the word MISSISSIPPI are arranged in a random order. 
Let $X$ be the number of Is that are immediately followed by an S. Find $E(X)$. 

The answer is $16/11$, and I keep getting $15/11$.

$P(X=1) = \frac{4}{11}$

$P(X=2) = \frac{2}{11}$

$P(X=3) = \frac{1}{11}$

$P(X=4) = \frac{1}{11}$

$\sum_x P(X) = 1(\frac{4}{11}) + 2(\frac{2}{11}) + 3(\frac{1}{11}) + 4(\frac{1}{11}) = \frac{15}{11}$

This question is in a conditional probability section, so I assume I am supposed to be using that.

Comment: We usually like it if you write out the work explicitly in the stack page. There are latex tutorials for Stack.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @JMoravitz  There are only $11$ letters in the word MISSISSIPPI.

Comment: @JMoravitz  If an I is in the last position, it cannot be followed by an S.   Therefore, should we multiply your answer by $\frac{10}{11}$ to account for the fact that the I in question must be in the first ten positions?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I realized that not long ago and am writing a full answer now.

Comment: There are $\binom{11}{4, 4, 2, 1} = \frac{11!}{4!4!2!1!}$ distinguishable arrangements of the word MISSISSIPPI.  If each of the four Is is followed by an S, we must arrange the seven objects IS, IS, IS, IS, P, P, M, which can be done in $\binom{7}{4, 2, 1} = \frac{7!}{4!2!1!}$ ways.  Hence, the probability that $X = 4$ is $$P(X = 4) = \frac{\frac{7!}{4!2!1!}}{\frac{11!}{4!4!2!1!}} = \frac{7!4!}{11!} = \frac{1}{330}$$  Calculating $P(X = 1)$, $P(X = 2)$, and $P(X = 3)$ is more difficult, so you would be better off using linearity of expectation, as in the answer provided by @JMoravitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let each letter also have a unique number, so we have $M_1I_1S_1S_2I_2S_3S_4I_3P_1P_2I_4$.  We have a total of eleven now *unique* letters.

Given that $I_i$ is not the last letter of the word each of the other letters are equally likely to follow it, of which four of those ten are $S$'s.  My earlier comments however missed the crucial first few words of that sentence though, that this is only assuming that our specific $I$ is not at the end of the word.  It will be in a position other than the last with probably $\frac{10}{11}$.

As such, the probability that $I_i$ is followed by an $S$ is therefore $\frac{10}{11}\cdot\frac{4}{10}=\frac{4}{11}$.

We define indicator random variables for our situation, i.e. random variables which take value either one or zero, as $X_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~I_i~\text{is followed by an}~S\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  We notice then that $E[X_i]=Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{4}{11}$ and we notice that $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$ counts the total number of $I$'s followed by $S$'s.

The expected number then of $I$'s followed by $S$'s will be by linearity of expectation: $$E[X]=E[X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+E[X_3]+E[X_4]=4\cdot\frac{4}{11}=\frac{16}{11}$$